# Updating 2D Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to go through each index of a 2d array and find what the neighbor values are and then update the index of the array based on that. My code below does all that but when I have to update the array it updates the existing array so the next index produces the incorrect output. I tried creating a new array but when I use the new array nothing is updated and it stays the same. This is what I have right now.

```
void ch(int **b, int w, int h)
{
    int x,y,i,ct=0;
    int **up;
    up=malloc(sizeof(int *) * h);
    for(i = 0; i<h; i++){
        up[i]=malloc(sizeof(int)*w);
    }

    for (x=0;x<h;x++)
    {
        for(y=0;y<w;y++)
        {
            //...Computes Count Here(It Works)
            //UPDATE BOARD - Does not update the board
            if(b[x][y]==1 && ct<2)
            {
                up[x][y]=0;
            }
            else if(b[x][y]==1 && (ct==2 || ct==3))
            {
                up[x][y]=1;
            }
            else if(b[x][y]==1 && ct>3)
            {
                up[x][y]=0;
            }
            else if(b[x][y]==0 && ct==3)
            {
                up[x][y]=1;
            }
            ct=0;
        }
    }
    b=up;
}
```

I tried updating the 2d array b by doing the changes on itself and it changes the array but it's not the output I am looking for. It changes the output at each iteration so output for other indexes changes but I want it so that another array keeps track of the output so that it does not update the b at every iteration and gives a correct out. What am I doing wrong that is not letting me update the up? What's the best approach to solve this issue?

Comment: Where is `count` defined?

Comment: @JoelCornett sorry it was a typo. I meant ct. updated the code!

Comment: You don't have an `else` clause to catch the impossible.  Maybe the impossible is happening rather too frequently?

Comment: Maybe you should try printing `up` in the function; that would show you that it is being set (or not).  You should return the new array — make the function `char **ch(int **b, int w, int h) { …; return up; }`.  Alternatively, you have to use a triple pointer argument, and make some adjustments to the code.  Note that if you overwrite the original array pointer, you have to worry about leaking memory.

Answer (score 0):

**C pass arguments by value**.

so you can do this way

```
int* pass(int *p){

//return new pointer; and later assign
}
```

or get  address

```
void pass(int **p)
{
 *p=//new pointer

}
```

**For your situation it is  better to modify the same array inside without allocating new**

> I cannot modify the same array

You can work on copy of array as suggested then update previous array from copy

Or just return that copied array as suggested by me

Worth a look:

[C Faq question related on your issue](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html)

[C Faq ways for  allocating multidimensional array](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html)

Comment: `new` isn't C its C++

Comment: I did not intend new.

Comment: I cannot modify the same array as it will screw up my count to modify the next index. Thats why I have to create a new array.

Comment: return that pointer. as on the first case. and also dont forget you have to free returned pointer after usage

Comment: I cannot change the return type. It has to be void. I have to leave it void and I am freeing everything in main.

Comment: you can do the second way and plus you have to double free b pointer to pointer. your will pass pointer to **b so will be ***b. Anyway if width ad height will not be changed better not to create new array and  if count is just value I beleive you can overcome it

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the original array and use that as a reference. Then you can update your original array directly.

```
void ch(int **b)
{
   int **up = malloc(sizeof(*int)*h);
   int i;
   for (i = 0; i < w; i++)
   {
       up[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * w);
       memcpy(up[i], b[i], w * sizeof(int));
   }
   //
   if (up[x][y] == 1)
       b[x][y] = 0;
}
// free up
```

This may be easier to maintain, than having an additional level of indirection as in

```
void ch(int ***b)
{
   int **up = *b;
   // do everything else as you intended

   // finalize with
   *b = up;
   // free up
}
```

Also when making the copy, you can increase the performance a bit by allocating the temporary copy as a linear array

```
int *up = malloc(sizeof(int) * w * h);

if (up[y * w + x] == 0)
    b[y][x] = 1;
```

Comment: This works but I dont think I am allowed to use memcpy. Is there a way I could copy the array without linking it the up to b?

Comment: Use the linearized array in that case: `for (i=0; i<w; i++) for (j=0;j<h;j++) up[i*w+j]=b[i][j];`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your function, where you have `b=up;`, you set `b` to point to your new array but that only changes your function's copy (`b`) and not the copy in the calling function... so the caller still sees the original array.

However, since you're using an array of pointers to arrays, rather than actual 2D arrays, you *can* replace the *contents* of `b` (the `int *`'s to the arrays making up the additional dimension)... and that will avoid having to copy all of your new array's data into the original array.

So instead of:

```
b=up;
```

try:

```
for(i = 0; i < h; i++) {
    free(b[i]);
    b[i] = up[i];
}
free(up);
```

That way each row of the original array gets replaced with the corresponding row from the new one, by changing the pointers in the original array of rows.

This is only a good idea, however, if the rows of the original array were dynamically allocated like the ones in your new array were, and if there are no other pointers to the rows floating around (outside of the array of rows passed as `b`) that might still point to the old memory afterward.

Comment: It prints the memory address out for the some of the int values.

Comment: What does the declaration of the original array look like?  Is it created like `up` is in your function?

Comment: Yes. Exactly like up.

Comment: I don't see where you could get pointer values into the row data from the change I suggested.  Unless `w` and `h` are backward...